# Out of memory and Internal Server Error while trying big scripts

Tags: php, large-data-volumes, fatal-error, out-of-memory, internal-server-error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 26214400) (tried to allocate 9175041 bytes) in ...
```

I am having this problem I noticed. I am getting the out of memory related 500 internet server error while trying to write big scripts. Big in the sense that I do a query that gives 4000 or 5000 rows, and I try writing them all using a foreach (for an excel extraction in this given case).

The php is giving exactly in the line that serves the foreach statement.

Anyone experienced to show me some light on this one please?

Comment: What kind of excel file are you generating? PHPExcel/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer build the file in memory and it can take up quite a bit of space. Allocating 9meg in one chunk is a pretty big allocation... How many columns are in each of these rows, and how much data in row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Fix:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

.htaccess Fix:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

php.ini Fix:

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit your php.ini file and increase the memory_limit.

Or, at the top of this script, include:

`ini_set("memory_limit","256M");`